# Multiple Facebook omniauth callback paths using omniauth-facebook in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" ..
I, [2015-06-12T01:28:27.556166 #77305]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.

Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQ....d8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-12 01:28:28 +0800
I, [2015-06-12T01:28:28.090435 #77305]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQ..p0", "state"=>"a6..d8"}
```

Above is my request log for the rails application I have that is doing omniauth request to Facebook. The problem is there is only one callback controllers that receives the Facebook omniauth response, which is in **omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**.

And the method has to handle many scenarios:

1. New user -> Register with Facebook
2. Login
3. Existing User -> Add Facebook identity
4. New user -> Get Facebook's email as user's email.

   ```
   def facebook
     @identity = Identity.find_for_oauth env["omniauth.auth"]
     @user = @identity.user || current_user

     if @user == current_user
       @user.sign_in_with << 'Facebook' if !(@user.sign_in_with.include? 'Facebook')
       @user.save!
     end

     if @user.nil?
       @user = User.create(email: @identity.email, sign_up_with: 'Facebook', sign_in_with: ['Facebook'])
       @identity.update_attribute(:user_id, @user.id)
     end

   ..
   end
   ```

I feel that the action is getting fat and chunky, and want to have a way to separate out the logic. is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I implemented the same functional. In this case I used **Advanced Constraints** for routes. It allows you provide an object that responds to `matches?` that Rails should use. I can demonstrate this approach by creating an account via FB and binding FB account with a custom existing profile. We separated this logic in a two actions. Since `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` might consist of a two actions for sign in/up and binding account with Facebook. Following the RESTful naming it might look like:

```
# for sign up or login with FB
def create
  @identity = Identity.find_for_oauth env["omniauth.auth"]
  # one ninja-code
end

# for binding FB account
def update
  # another ninja-code
end
```

So you can make two constraint files like a modules, e.g.

for login account action like a `lib/login_facebook_contstraint.rb`

```
class LoginFacebookConstraint

  def matches?(request)
    request.query_parameters["bind"].blank?
  end
end
```

and for binding account action like a `lib/bind_facebook_contstraint.rb`

```
class BindFacebookConstraint

  def matches?(request)
    request.query_parameters["bind"].present?
  end
end
```

In binding case you can add to request params `bind: true` or something like that, e.g when we use **Facebook Javascript SDK** it might look like this:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback?' +
      $.param({
        signed_request: response.authResponse.signedRequest,
        bind: true
      });
  }
}, {scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email'});
```

And then you can control routing in `routes.rb`

```
# Callbacks for authorized provider
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'omniauth_callbacks#create',
  constraints: LoginFacebookConstraint.new
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'omniauth_callbacks#update',
  constraints: BindFacebookConstraint.new
```

Now if you have a request with `bind: true` parameter it will be handled by `update` action in `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` and you can get params from facebook in a both cases

```
def auth_params
  request.env["omniauth.auth"]
end
```

This approach allow you separate out logic.
Sources - [Advanced Constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints), [Facebook Login SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

I hope I have helped you to find a more elegant solution.